# Getting access to external Storage files and sending them as a email attachment

Tags: java, android-studio, email, attachment, fileprovider

I want to send an email with attached pdf files. When I am trying to send them over URI I get this error message:

```
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///Download/myPDFFile.pdf exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
```

So I tryed to do the same with the fileprovider. Here I get this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.digitalpaper.provider
```

```
                String filename="myPDFFile.pdf";

                File testFile = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);

                Uri path =    FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(getApplicationContext()),BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", testFile);


               //----------------Sending the Mail----------------//
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailIntent.setType("application/pdf");
                String to[] = {"xyz@gmx.de",eT_email.getText().toString()};
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);

                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject");


//-----------------------Attaching the file---------------------------------//

                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
              //  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse( "file://"+filelocation));

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Send email..."));
```

I already tried several ways to accomplish that Email attachment but I am never able to access my external storage. Do someone know how to solve that ?